# How do we convert double nested dictionary to a list in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to convert

```
dct = {"a":1,"b":{"c":2,"d":{"z":5,"t":12}}}
```

to

```
lst = ["a:1","b:c:2","b:d:z:5","b:d:t:12"]
```

in Python?

Comment: Why? How do you plan to use your `list`?

Comment: What have you tried so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: Sounds like a good candidate for a recursive function...

Comment: Recursion or at least separate functions seems to be the cleanest/easiest to read way to do this.

Comment: recursion is the way to go in this one, already was writing a solution, but for some reason, this question is now closed. Yes, it's not high effort, but it was pretty obvious what OP was after

Answer (score 2):

Recursively:

```
def flatten(dct, path="",lst=None):
    if not lst: lst = []
    for key,value in dct.items():
        if type(value) is dict:
            flatten(value, f"{path}{key}:", lst)
        else:
            lst.append(f"{path}{key}:{value}")
    return lst

print(flatten({"a":1,"b":{"c":2,"d":{"z":5,"t":12}}}))
```

Outputs:

```
['a:1', 'b:c:2', 'b:d:z:5', 'b:d:t:12']
```

Another version, as suggested in the comments.
Credit to: @Ch3steR

```
def flatten(dct, path=""):
    lst = []
    for key,value in dct.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            lst.extend(flatten(value, f"{path}{key}:"))
        else:
            lst.append(f"{path}{key}:{value}")
    return lst
 
print(flatten({"a":1,"b":{"c":2,"d":{"z":5,"t":12}}}))
```

Comment: The solution would be a victim of ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/12416453)

Comment: @Ch3steR Yeah. Updated.

Comment: can't you just remove it from the parameters, and have it inside? `lst = []`

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh No. That would create a new list each time the function is recursively called and I only want one list. Well, you probably could and return it and combine with previous list, but I think this is easier.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp You can try something like this: https://ideone.com/hp5dHB

Comment: One more suggestion would be using `isinstance`. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1549801/12416453

Comment: @Ch3steR Thanks for the input. As a primarily C++ programmer who occasionally works in Python, it is always welcome.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I'm really glad you took it in a positive way. I learnt Python through SO never took a course. It was only possible due to many helpful individuals who suggested best practices in python in the comments. I'm doing the same helping the community in my capacity. :)